# Best practice to perform two times groupbykey in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, batch-processing

I've a lot of tuples with this kind of format:

```
(1,200,a)
(2,300,a)
(1,300,b)
(2,400,a)
(2,500,b)
(3,200,a)
(3,400,b)
(1,500,a)
(2,400,b)
(3,500,a)
(1,200,b)
```

My job is to sort in firt time the tuple for the first integer, and then doing the average of the value in the second element of the tuple for each element of the third element of the tuple.
So, the result should be this:

```
(1,350,a),
(1,250,b),
(2,350,a),
(2,450,b),
(3,350,a),
(3,400,b).
```

What kind of best practice do you reccomend in this case?
I've tried to do MaptoPair and then groupbykey for the first element of the tuple. Then another MapTopPair and groupbykey for the third element and then reducebykey, but it doesn't work and i don't know why. I don't think  i've used the best practice for resolving this type of job.

[This is a sketch of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8qhv.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Is there some code related to that ? Or do you think we'll do all for you ?

Comment: i just would like to know the best practice, of course i've the code but there isn't bug or anything else, just to know if the logic is correct

Comment: map to pair and use reducebykey to find the average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Dataset` API. Here in Scala, but Java will be almost identical:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1,200,"a"), (2,300,"a"), (1,300,"b"), (2,400,"a"), (2,500,"b"),
  (3,200,"a"), (3,400,"b"), (1,500,"a"), (2,400,"b"), (3,500,"a"),
  (1,200,"b")
))

val df = rdd.toDF("k1", "v", "k2")

df.groupBy("k1", "k2").mean("v").orderBy("k1", "k2").show

+---+---+------+
| k1| k2|avg(v)|
+---+---+------+
|  1|  a| 350.0|
|  1|  b| 250.0|
|  2|  a| 350.0|
|  2|  b| 450.0|
|  3|  a| 350.0|
|  3|  b| 400.0|
+---+---+------+
```

With RDD map first to have composite key:

```
rdd
  .map(x => ((x._1, x._3), (x._2, 1.0)))
  .reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
  .mapValues(x => x._1 / x._2)
  .take(6).foreach(println)


((2,a),350.0)
((3,b),400.0)
((1,b),250.0)
((1,a),350.0)
((3,a),350.0)
((2,b),450.0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, foolishly i didn't think to use a key with two value, this is why i tried to do two mapToPair in cascade.